# Prove that there is no bipartite graph on $14$ vertices with this degree sequence.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that there is no bipartite graph on $14$ vertices with degree sequence:
>   $$6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.$$

I assume a vertex with degree $5$ breaks this graph from being bipartite.

I was thinking to let the number of vertices with degree $3 = x$ and those with degree $5 = y$. I'm still thinking about what to do from there...

Answer (score 4):

Because the graph is bipartite, the sum of the degrees of the vertices on the left side is equal to the sum of the degrees of the vertices on the right side. They both are equal to half of the sum of the numbers you are given. You need to show that no subset of those numbers has a sum that is equal to half of the sum of all the numbers. Hint: modular arithmetic.

Comment: I'm going to need to learn modular arithmetic. That will be a few weeks away.

Answer (score 1):

If I counted correctly, the total degree sum is 68.
That means each side of the bipartition must have a degree sum of 34.
And 34 is not a multiple of 3 (thus no side can have a degree sum that's a multiple of 3).

Now, take the side of the bipartition that *doesn't* have the degree 5 vertex.
What about its degree sum ?

Comment: Where does the multiple of 3 part come in?Why is it important that  no side can have a degree sum that's a multiple of 3

Comment: If you look at the degrees, they're all 3 and 6 (except for one vertex of degree 5).  Now, in the bipartition, there is a side $X$ that doesn't have this vertex of degree 5.  That means $X$ has only vertices or degree 3 or 6.  Then the sum of degrees of $X$ must be a multiple of 3.  But it's not because this sum is 34.  Therefore this graph can't exist.

Comment: :Thanks for the help